# histogram of matrix with xlim

Tags: matlab, matrix, histogram

I have a m-by-n matrix of values between 10^-20 and 10^-8
I drew it by

```
figure();
hist(My_mat(:),15);
```

I obtain only one bins of the hist,also with '15' but I would to obtain several of bins between min and max values
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Tyoe `help hist`, the second parameter specifies the number of bins: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html

Comment: Yes thank you, I know the second parameter, I forgot to specify it in my post and I just updated.

Comment: What does your My_mat look like?

Comment: @EJG89 is a matrix 300-by-600 of double

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. To draw a histogram having arbitrary bins use:

```
nbins=10;
figure();
hist(data,nbins)
```

However, if no second argument is given the standard of 10 bins is used. I suspect your vector contains all identical numbers therefore yielding only a single column. Could you verify this?

Kind regards,

Ernst Jan

Comment: I modified my post because I had not specified the nbins=15. The vector does not contains all identical numbers

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (I get 15 bins):

```
C=rand(300,600)*1e-20;   % to have similar numbers as you have
nbins = 15;
hist(C(:),nbins);
```

If you still have problems, try

```
close all; clearvars;
```

before executing the rest.